# How to open new activity after cardview clicked?

Tags: java, android, xml

How to open new activity after cardview clicked ?
I have CardView and RecyclerView, then I loop my data with RecycleView.

Comment: to start navigation from one activity to another activity                           new Intent(startActivity(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));

Comment: Next time search for `"android how to open new activity"` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
card.setOnClickListener(...); //card is CardView
```

Then handel onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(Card c ,View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: How to cange my toast open new activity ?
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "This iS " + cityName.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

Answer (score 0):

if Recyclerview inside cardeview then as below

[image]